# Como sincronizar SQLite com MySQL

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Tenho um aplicativo em Ionic e Angular que recebe informações por meio de um `$http`. Gostaria de saber como mantenho as informações *offline* do aplicativo atualizada com as do banco MySQL sempre que uma conexão seja estabelecida. Como posso sincronizar automaticamente o banco SQLite com o MySQL?

Já pesquisei mais não tive um retorno agradável a única coisa que encontrei foi [WebSqlSync](https://github.com/orbitaloop/WebSqlSync) mas não consegui usar.

Comment: Preencha a pergunta com mais informações para podermos lhe ajudar. O que já tentou ou pesquisou? Você tem dúvida exatamente em que partes? Caso a pergunta não seja editada, corre o risco de ser fechada.

Comment: desculpe ja foi corrigido!